# 403 Forbidden from Nginx container in Docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am trying to render a static file with my nginx server. My static files - index.html and login.html is in public/templates/index.html and public/templates/login.html respectively. The problem is I get a 403 forbidden error each time, I run my localhost server. If I move the static files (index.html and login.html) from the templates directory to public directory, it renders perfectly. I am using docker to manage both nginx and and localhost server.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM php:7
RUN pecl install ev-beta && \
   docker-php-ext-enable ev
WORKDIR /opt/app
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/php", "server.php"]
```

**Nginx Server Configuration File(nginx.conf)**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log warn;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade{
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #root /var/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @phpsite;
}

location @phpsite {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://app:8080;
}
}
```

**Server.php**

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/SlimAdapterServer.php';
require_once 'src/SessionProvider.php';

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$provider = new \Authentication\SessionProvider();
$slim = new \Slim\App();

//HomePage Route;
$slim->get('/', function(Request $req, Response $res) use ($provider): Response{

$sessionId = $req->getCookieParams()['session'] ?? '';

if(!$provider->hasSession($sessionId)){
  return $res->withRedirect('/login');
}

$res->getBody()->write(file_get_contents('templates/index.html'));
return $res->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf8');
});

//Login Route
$slim->get('/login', function(Request $req, Response $res): Response {
$res->getBody()->write(file_get_contents('templates/login.html'));
return $res->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf8');
});

$adapter = new \Http\SlimAdapterServer($slim);

$app = new \Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080, '0.0.0.0');
$app->route('/', $adapter, ['*']);
$app->route('/login', $adapter, ['*']);
$app->route('/authenticate', $adapter, ['*']);
$app->run();
```

I would like my php script to detect if a user is logged-in, if yes redirect to the index.html page else redirect to login.html page.

**Error Logs from Docker Webserver Container**

```
172.17.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2017:20:44:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "-" "curl/7.54.0" "-" 2017/12/11 20:44:02 [error] 6#6: *8 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: You need to add your docker-compose file otherwise we can't see how your docker services are setup.

Comment: @Alkaline, thank you for the tip. I have added Dockerfile to the post. Its the only file that I used to set up docker images. Is there anywhere I can get docker compose file from docker?

Comment: This article will almost certainly address your issue, my guess is it's the first one and you've got permission problems: http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/ . Make sure you check permissions on the directory and files.

Comment: @xbakesx, From the article, I understand that I have to give file permissions to my static directories (755) and files(644). The root of the Nginx server is /usr/share/nginx/html . I can't find this directory from my terminal, I guess it's in docker. How can I access this directory so that I can modify the permissions?

Comment: Well... it looks like you've got several problems.  I don't know anything about the php container, but it doesn't look like you ever copy your server.php file into your docker container.  Also I bet nginx is attempting to serve up files from /usr/share/nginx/html but that directory isn't created so you're getting a 403.  You can `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` to get a shell into your container and look around at what's there.

Comment: Where all the files you expected to be in there in there? (server.php, index.html and login.html)  I'm not sure if you want your server.php in /usr/share/nginx/html or in /opt/app.  Seems to me the Docker CMD expects it in /opt/app but the nginx will expect it in /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: @xbakesx, I have two containers. The first container -chat-app has all my files: dockerfile, server.php file, public  directory. The public directory has a template directory, which has my static files(index.html, and login.html). The chat-container is using the nginx server and its listening on port 80. The second container -chat web, has the /usr/share/nginx/html/templates directory. It also has the static files.

Comment: @xbakesx, if the static files are in the public directory the work perfectly. But when I move the files to the template directory which is inside the public directory, I get the 403 forbidden error...

Comment: @xbakesx, thank you for the tips you gave me yesterday, I have been playing and finally found out that the nginx.conf file from docker was configured differently from the nginx.conf on my computer root directly. So now, I am trying to download vim inside the bash env so that I can edit the configuration file. I used the steps from this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336392/e-unable-to-locate-package-vim-on-debian-jessie-simplified-docker-container/366538#366538?newreg=8fdeaa8ec5c147c6a9f4a149fe10ebee) and it's not working. Are there any editors that comes installed with bash?

Comment: Something like `apt-get update && apt-get install vim` should work once you shell in.  However you could try `nano`.  Other options would `cat nginx.conf | sed [make changes] > nginx.conf` to make changes that way or you can `docker cp ...` the file out of docker make changes and then make sure that as part of your Dockerfile you put that changed file in the right place.  That way you have control

Comment: @xbakesk It worked :-) :-) thank you.